# BadImageFormatException thrown when running NUnit tests on TeamCity

Tags: .net, nunit, teamcity

I have a unit test project using NUnit 2.6.3 using .Net 4.5. But in the teamcity build step configuration I only have runtime 4.0 available (even if other components of my solution are compile against 4.5) and when I run my unit test I get the following exception :

```
    [Step 8/9] System.ArgumentException: Specified NUnit error running tests in '[SANITIZED].UnitTest.dll' assembly
Loading assembly is compiled for v4.0.30319, MSIL
NUnit runner runtime is v4.0.30319, x64
System.ArgumentException: A BadImageFormatException has been thrown while parsing the signature. This is likely due to lack of a generic context. Ensure genericTypeArguments and genericMethodArguments are provided and contain enough context. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '[SANITIZED]' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.InstallAdhocExtensions(Assembly assembly)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.NUnitRunner.LoadTest(String testAssembly, String testName, TestRunner runner) in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\NUnit-2.6\NUnitRunner.cs:line 53
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.AssemblyTest.LoadTestDomain() in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\AssemblyTest.cs:line 76
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.LoadTestDomainAction.Action(AssemblyTest test) in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\LoadTestDomainAction.cs:line 17
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.TryOneAssemblyTest.Action() in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\TryOneAssemblyTest.cs:line 18
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.TryOneAssembly.Do() in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\TryOneAssembly.cs:line 36
Check correct .NET Framework version and process platform (x64, x86, MSIL) are used both in the test runner settings and involved assemblies on this machine. description. description should be non-null string of (0, 4000] size
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.CommonLoggers.Impl.BuildProblemServiceMessageImpl.AddBuildProblem(String identity, String type, String description) in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\CommonLoggers\src\Impl\BuildProblemServiceMessageImpl.cs:line 43
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.TryOneAssembly.Do() in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\TryOneAssembly.cs:line 64
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.NUnitRunnerBase.DoTry(TryOneAssembly aTry) in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\NUnitRunnerBase.cs:line 53
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.NUnitRunnerBase.RunOneAssembly(AssemblyTest test, ITestOrderingStrategy strategy, Boolean isRecentTestMode) in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\NUnitRunnerBase.cs:line 161
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.NUnitRunnerBase.RunInternal() in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\NUnitRunnerBase.cs:line 141
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitLauncher.NUnitRunnerBase.Run() in c:\BuildAgent\work\42f5b4bce579465c\src\NUnitLauncher\src\NUnitRunnerBase.cs:line 60
```

Any idea to help me to configure these unit tests ?

Comment: Try to edit configuration of your TeamCity job, choose **NUnit runner** 2.6.3 and **.NET runtime** x86, v4.0, currently it seems you have x64.

Comment: @MichalHosala : Thanks, that fixed the issue ! Can you post it as answer so I can mark it as solution and mark the question as fixed ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace and [NUnit release notes](http://www.nunit.org/?p=releaseNotes&r=2.6.3) my impression is that the problem is *not* with NUnit 2.6.3 targeting v4.0 platform.

It more likely seems to be an issue with bitness of the NUnit test runner, which in your job is x64:

> NUnit runner runtime is v4.0.30319, x64

The `BadImageFormatException` can be then thrown if your MSIL compiled test assembly is trying to load some x86 library or similarly.

Simply changing the configuration of your TeamCity job to use 32bit NUnit runner (.NET runtime v4.0, x86) should fix the issue.